# Failed brownie import when running scripts

Tags: solidity, python, brownie, import

I am trying to setup `eth-brownie` to get a feel of the framework but face a couple of import-related problems.

Im working from a MBP running macOS with **Catalina v10.15.7**

```
$ python --version
Python 3.9.9
```

I have followed the recommendations from https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html and could get `brownie` to run fine in CLI.

See following:

```
$ pipx list
venvs are in /Users/julien.couvy/.local/pipx/venvs
apps are exposed on your $PATH at /Users/julien.couvy/.local/bin
   package eth-brownie 1.17.1, Python 3.9.9
    - brownie

$ brownie --version
Brownie v1.17.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum
```

I have tried compiling a sample brownie-box and run the tests, which worked fine.

```
brownie test
Brownie v1.17.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum

Compiling contracts...
  Solc version: 0.6.12
  Optimizer: Enabled  Runs: 200
  EVM Version: Istanbul
Generating build data...
 - SafeMath
 - Token

=============================================================================================================== test session starts ===============================================================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.9.9, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.10.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /Users/(...)/sample-contracts/token
plugins: eth-brownie-1.17.1, web3-5.24.0, hypothesis-6.24.0, xdist-1.34.0, forked-1.3.0
collected 38 items                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

Launching 'ganache-cli --port 8545 --gasLimit 12000000 --accounts 10 --hardfork istanbul --mnemonic brownie'...

tests/test_approve.py ............                                                                                                                                                                                                          [ 31%]
tests/test_transfer.py .........                                                                                                                                                                                                            [ 55%]
tests/test_transferFrom.py .................                                                                                                                                                                                                [100%]

=============================================================================================================== 38 passed in 10.93s ===============================================================================================================
Terminating local RPC client...
```

When trying to import `brownie` in a python program via VSCode, it does not resolve. This is probably due to the fact that VSCode does not manage to find the `venv` used by `pipx`.

Moreover, I cannot run any individual script using `brownie run`, see example:

```
$ brownie run scripts/token.py
 
Brownie v1.17.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum

TokenProject is the active project.

Launching 'ganache-cli --port 8545 --gasLimit 12000000 --accounts 10 --hardfork istanbul --mnemonic brownie'...
  File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 50, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "brownie/project/scripts.py", line 53, in run
    module = _import_from_path(script)
  File "brownie/project/scripts.py", line 149, in _import_from_path
    _import_cache[import_str] = importlib.import_module(import_str)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Users.eval'
Terminating local RPC client...
```

I have tried installing `eth-brownie` using `pip3` in a dedicated `venv` instead of going the `pipx` route. This seem to allow VSCode to find the module, but still cannot use `brownie run`

Answer (score 1):

Further research has led me to this previous post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68721661/eth-brownie-no-module-named-users-someuser

I have edited the `__import_from_path` function in my brownie install at `~/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/lib/python3.9/site-packages/brownie/project/scripts.py` with the suggested edit and it seems to have fixed the import problem

Another potential solution for VSCode import (linting issue) is to select `pipx` venv as a Python interpreter:

`CTRL+CMD+P` > `Python: select Interpreter` > `~/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/bin/python`

After that, the linting error disappeared. I will try to write a few simple contracts and see how it goes.